# get client's GMT offset in javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, timezone-offset

how can I get the GMT offset in javascript of the client?

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset();` returns the difference from UTC. Is there a way I can calculate the GMT offset from that?

By GMT offset, I mean as in -5 for eastern standard time.

Comment: you can't unless you convert UTC to GMT.

Comment: @DanielA.White How do I do that? In javascript?

Comment: yea - theres libraries out there.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you post an answer with a reliable one and how to use it so I can select it, please.

Comment: checkout moment timezone. that kind of question is off topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because UTC *is* GMT.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi How so? I am getting values in the hundreds for UTC and GMT is + or - 12 or less?

Comment: @user, do you mean `UTC-0500` or `GMT-5`? Same thing, different representation.

Comment: I don't agree with closing the question. The OP is asking how to convert an ECMAScript time zone offset to an ISO 8601 format offset from UTC. Far better to [*explain the difference between UTC and GMT*](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html) and then answer the question (UTC is a time standard, GMT is a timezone, they both represent the same time but are different things).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); returns the difference from UTC. Is there a way I can calculate the GMT offset from that?

The timezone offset **is** the difference from GMT in minutes (see [ECMA-262 §15.9.5.26](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26)). The sign is the reverse of ISO 8601, but it's easily converted to hours and minutes with a more standard sign:

```
function getTimezoneOffset() {
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n}
  var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  var sign = offset < 0? '+' : '-';
  offset = Math.abs(offset);
  return sign + z(offset/60 | 0) + z(offset%60);
}

getTimezoneOffset() // +0800 for UTC/GMT + 8hrs
```

If you want to determine the IANA timezone designation, you can try [*pellepim jstimezonedetect*](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect), however it works by guessing based on the offset for two dates and may not be correct.

Comment: Note, depending on usage, one may want to include a colon character (`:') between the hour and minute components of the offset.  Easily done on the last line of the function.

Comment: does this handle cases like xx:30?

Comment: Yes. The string returned includes the sign, hours and minutes.

Comment: can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart to siplify the z() function.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the bitwise OR operator here: `z(offset/60 | 0)`. Isn't `offset/60 | 0` always going to evaluate to `offset/60`?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. It's for when the offset/60 is not an integer, e.g. `3.5|0 = 3`.